# Stealing Cookies with no user input?

Tags: python, security, xss

I'm creating a static site generator with a dynamic admin backend for one user. The site accepts no user input. Does this mean that I am safe from attackers who are trying to steal my admin cookie?

(there is no user input, so XSS and other methods don't work, right?)

Comment: The Admin module - is it served on the same domain and served over the internet? For example, if your admin page is only served on local intranet and you trust your intranet/co-workers, then its okay not to worry. Otherwise, you still have to worry about someone stealing your admin cookie, and everything mentioned below applies.

Comment: .. additionally, you have to be diligent not to visit malicious websites or click on links via email/im/chat while you are logged in to the admin dashboard. Otherwise someone can csrf you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's *no* user input (no links to click that have any effects, etc.), how does the admin backend qualify as "dynamic"?

But basically: No, not unless you're using HTTPS. Even if you're not accepting input, the cookie is transmitted in plaintext and so can be captured (by a man-in-the-middle attack, etc.) and used. (I assume you don't want other people using the cookie to see the admin stuff.)

Or did I completely misunderstand the question? ;-)

Comment: I'll clarify: The website accepts no user input. It serves pages, the contents of which are stored in a mysql database. There is an "admin dashboard" where I can edit the contents of existing entries or add in new ones. I only want my computer to have access to this feature. I am planning to differentiate my computer from potential attackers by checking for a valid admin cookie. Even with just a front-end static site, is it possible for someone to somehow steal my cookie and get access to my admin dashboard?

Comment: @Yongho: If anyone can get the cookie (via access to your computer, or network sniffing, etc.), then yes, they can get access. So that's what you're defending against. If you can require your admin access to *only* work over HTTPS (not HTTP), that'll deal with the network sniffing aspect, leaving your computer's cookie storage as the weak spot. Also beware brute force attacks by logging and *looking at* the logs to be aware of failed attempts to access your admin console (someone may be trying to guess the cookie). You get the idea. :-)

Comment: @Yongho - If you keep your admin dashboard on a separate domain, and serve that domain only on the local intranet, and take care not to visit any other website or click any link while you have an active admin session, you are okay. If any of these conditions don't hold true, you'd have to fix your vulnerabilities.

Comment: @sri That was actually the approach I was leaning toward. One question: how would I serve the domain only on the local intranet? I feel that checking IP wouldn't be enough security for that. (can be spoofed right?)

Comment: @Yongho - IP addresses cannot be spoofed, in the sense that an attacker cannot have a meaningful tcp session with a spoofed ip address. The typical way to serve administrative interfaces is to have two NICs, one public and the private. Each NIC would have a different IP address, and you'd set up your domains to point to the corresponding IP Address. How to setup and configure such a system is beyond the scope of stackoverflow. You'd have to post your question on serverfault.com to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following feature is a point of vulnerability. This could be a vector in which could be accessed in a nefarious means using CSRF. Malicious JavaScript maybe introduced by performing a `CSRF->Stored XSS` attack.

> There is an "admin dashboard" where I
>   can edit the contents of existing
>   entries or add in new ones.

The problem being that when you are authenticated to this administrative console a hacker can still access this feature by "riding" on your authenticated session and this is the basis of [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).  In short,  the attacker *doesn't need to know your session id* because your browser does!  By visiting a malicious website an attacker can force your browser into sending an http request to your administrative console.   In order to pull off this attack the attacker must know the server,  the path to the script, and all of the POST/GET parameters,  but he doesn't need your password or cookie.  If this is an in-house administrative console that this is an unlikely attack vector.  But its easy to defend against.  The easiest method would be to check the http `referer` of an http request that is making this "content modification",  Motorola does this for many of their network appliances.  A more common approach is to use a "csrf token".

CSRF is **still** a problem if you are using basic-auth via an .htaccess file or a cookie based auth.  No matter what you need to prevent malicious forged requests and protect against sniffing by using HTTPS.   This is gone into greater detail in the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project),  make sure to read "A3: Broken Authentication and Session Management".